# Fat arrow push results to new function

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm fairly new to Angular (2) and typescript.

I have service where I make an http call and I'm trying to push the result of the call into another function.

Here is the code:

```
  login(user){
    //I want to make this call
    this.http.post(this.API_ENDPOINT+'/authenticate', user) =>
      //Then return the results to this function
      this.storeUserCredentials(user); 
  }
```

My thought was to use a fat arrow function to push the result, but I know this is totally off.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can do that :

```
// With the consideration this.http is Http and not HttpClient
this.http.post(this.API_ENDPOINT+'/authenticate', user)
.map(res => res.json())
.subscribe(user => {
    this.storeUserCredentials(user); 
})
```

Comment: It's not evident that http is Http and not HttpClient, because the OP withheld this information.